# How to use if statment in View (@doc.value == "N/A" )

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use a if statement to display records in a cell where the field DocumentType = "N/A" and then again in a different cell where the field DocumentType <> "N/A". How can this be done. I can not seem to get it correct. Here is what I am trying.

```
 @foreach (Document documents in Model.Documents)
   {
     if (@documents.DocumentType == "N/A")
     {
      <tr>
       <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 1px"><a href="@documents.Document_url">@documents.Description</a></td>
      </tr>
     }
   }


 @foreach (Document documents in Model.Documents)
   {
     if (@documents.DocumentType != "N/A")
     {
      <tr>
       <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 1px"><a href="@documents.Document_url">@documents.Description</a></td>
      </tr>
     }
   }
```

Comment: you should describe some more about what you require.. as i got for cell change you should make a `<td>` in the same upper loop or if you want that in the other row then put `else if` condition with in the upper loop to display in the next row other cell

Comment: I am attempting using 2 different tables to show results for all records with the DocumentType of "N/A" in 1 table (cell) and everything else other then DocumentType of "N/A" in another table (cell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me the approach looks ok. But it sounds like it will be better to use linq.

The list can be filtered on the foreach statement:

```
@foreach (Document documents in Model.Documents.Where(d => d.DocumentType == "N/A"))
{
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 1px"><a href="@documents.Document_url">@documents.Description</a></td>
    </tr>
}

@foreach (Document documents in Model.Documents.Where(d => d.DocumentType != "N/A"))
{
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 1px"><a href="@documents.Document_url">@documents.Description</a></td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: When I try this is gives me: cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type.

Comment: I just figured it out. My DocumentType was null for some reason. I am going to do it the way you showed though!!